# Fluent NHibernate returns one item on Eager Loading

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a little problem with FLuent NHibernate.
My classes are:

```
public class Usuario
    {
        public virtual long IdUsuario { get; set; }
        public virtual string AdSamAccountName { get; set; }
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual TrabajadorWenco TrabajadorWenco { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<AsignacionProyecto> ProyectosAsignados { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<UsuarioArea> AreasUsuario { get; set; }
    }

public class Area
    {
        public virtual long IdArea { get; set; }
        public virtual string Nombre { get; set; }
        public virtual string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<UsuarioArea> UsuariosArea { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Proyecto> ProyectosArea { get; set; }
    }
public class UsuarioArea
    {
        public virtual long IdUsuarioArea { get; set; }
        public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
        public virtual Area Area { get; set; }
        public virtual Rol Rol { get; set; }
    }
```

My Maps are:

```
class UsuarioMap : ClassMap<Usuario>
    {
        public UsuarioMap()
        {
            Schema("dbo");
            Table("usuario");

            Id(x => x.IdUsuario).Column("id_usuario")
                .GeneratedBy.HiLo("dbo.nh_hilo", "next_hi", "1000", @"table_name = 'usuario'");

            References(x => x.TrabajadorWenco).Column("id_trabajador_wenco").Not.LazyLoad();
            HasMany(x => x.ProyectosAsignados).KeyColumn("id_asignacion_proyecto");
            HasMany(x => x.AreasUsuario).KeyColumn("id_usuario_area").Not.LazyLoad();

            Map(x => x.AdSamAccountName).Column("ad_sam_account_name");
            Map(x => x.Email).Column("email");
        }
    }
public class UsuarioAreaMap : ClassMap<UsuarioArea>
    {
        public UsuarioAreaMap()
        {
            Schema("sgh");
            Table("usuario_area");

            Id(x => x.IdUsuarioArea).Column("id_usuario_area")
                .GeneratedBy.HiLo("dbo.nh_hilo", "next_hi", "1000", @"table_name = 'usuario_area'");

            References(x => x.Usuario).Column("id_usuario");
            References(x => x.Area).Column("id_area").Not.LazyLoad();

            Map(x => x.Rol).CustomType(typeof(Rol)).Column("id_rol");
        }
    }
public class AreaMap : ClassMap<Area>
    {
        public AreaMap()
        {
            Schema("sgh");
            Table("area");

            Id(x => x.IdArea).Column("id_area")
                .GeneratedBy.HiLo("dbo.nh_hilo", "next_hi", "1000", @"table_name = 'area'");

            HasMany(x => x.UsuariosArea).KeyColumn("id_area");
            HasMany(x => x.ProyectosArea).KeyColumn("id_area");

            Map(x => x.Nombre).Column("nombre");
            Map(x => x.Descripcion).Column("descripcion");
        }
    }
```

I know there are two records for Usuario with Id = 1 in the table UsuarioArea, but when i try to make a FindById It returns me a Usuario but with just one item in the list UsuariosArea.

Any clue about why does it return me just one item in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference your foreign key in the hasmany mapping

Try changing it to :

```
HasMany(x => x.AreasUsuario).KeyColumn("id_usuario").Not.LazyLoad();
```

Comment: Assuming that my foreign key is "id_usuario" yes. It works for me :). Thxs